# Windows Phone/Windows 8-style horizontal scrolling in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, touch, scrollviewer

I'm writing an app in C# WPF and I'm hoping to implement a similar kind of touch-based horizontal scrolling that's featured prominently in Windows 8.
At the moment I'm using ScrollViewer with content inside it. This works fine as far as the scrolling is concerned, but it creates problems when interacting with controls inside of it (for example, sliders).

With my limited programming knowledge (a month ago the most I'd done was create a mockup in Photoshop :P), I'd assume this was because the touch hits the ScrollViewer first? Is there some way of flipping this around? I would be happy even if you had to hit a white space to be able to scroll, I just need the user to be able to interact with the controls inside easily without accidentally scrolling all over the place ^_^

Unfortunately, I can't just code for Windows 8 as this is specifically for a bunch of touch-enabled Windows 7 machines.

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Developer-Preview-6b53adbb http://code.jenkinsfamily.com.au/mahapps.metro/wiki/Home

Answer (score 0):

Look for the [Metro theme here](http://metrotheme.codeplex.com/) you might find some usful style here that you can modify and use..

Also you can check [this](http://softwarebytes.blogspot.com/2010/12/wpf-metro-window.html) website for information and guidelines on Metro UI on WPF

Comment: Thanks for that, but that seems to be more along the lines of styling rather than affecting the user interaction

Comment: I belive you might find some style that might help you on the Touch based UI. I have never developed a touch based UI but i believe WinPhone 7 themes might help